# MPI_WTIME is not giving me speedup as required

Tags: fortran, mpi

```
Program Main
implicit none
include 'mpif.h'
!Define parameters
integer::my_rank,p2,n2,ierr,source
integer, parameter :: n=3,m=3,o=m*n
real(kind=8) aaa(n),ddd(n),bbb(n),ccc(n),xxx(n),b(m,n),start, finish
integer i, j
real h
real(kind=8),dimension(:),allocatable::sol1
h=0.25
b=0
do i=1,m
b(i,i)=1/(1.2**i)
b(i,i-1)=-b(i,i)
enddo

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,p2,ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,my_rank,ierr)
allocate(sol1(o))
start=MPI_WTIME()
do i=1,n

aaa(i)=-1/h**2
bbb(i)=2/h**2+b(my_rank+1,my_rank+1)
ccc(i)=-1/h**2
ddd(i)=1/h**2
enddo
call thomas(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,xxx,n)
finish=MPI_WTIME()
print*, finish-start
write(*,*) xxx, my_rank
call MPI_GATHER(xxx,n, MPI_REAL, sol1,n,MPI_REAL8,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
print*,sol1
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end program main

subroutine thomas(ld,md,ud,rh,solution,n)
implicit none
    integer,parameter :: r8 = kind(1.d0)
    integer,intent(in) :: n
    real(r8),dimension(n),intent(in) :: ld,md,ud,rh
    real(r8),dimension(n),intent(out) :: solution
    real(r8),dimension(n) :: P,Q
    real(r8) :: m
    integer i
    P(1) = ud(1)/md(1)
    Q(1) = rh(1)/md(1)
     do i = 2,n
       m = md(i)-p(i-1)*ld(i)
       P(i) = ud(i)/m
       Q(i) = (rh(i)-Q(i-1)*ld(i))/m
     end do
     solution(n) = Q(n)
    do i = n-1, 1, -1
      solution(i) = Q(i)-P(i)*solution(i+1)
    end do

end subroutine thomas
```

Here I used MPI_WTIME() to find the execution time. It seems like when I increase the number of processor than I am not getting the speedup. In this code I have m=3 (I make m equal equal to no of processor). I run with mpirun -np 3 sp.exe). Now I change say m=10 and run with mpirun -np 10 sp.exe.  I should get the  less time, isn't it? or I am missing something here. The community helped me before with some issues and now I am getting another issue. I would really appreciate the help if somebody would point out something.Isn't the chunk of code starting with do loop done by invidual processors( which I want)?

Comment: do you always have `m=n`? if so, it looks like you are doing weak scaling, so your target is to keep the time to solution constant when you increase *both* the number of MPI tasks *and* the problem size.

Comment: Actually if m=n (which to be fair the OP doesn't say is the general case) as written the amount of work per process increases with the number of processes, rather than staying constant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you are doing here. For speed up the general idea is to have a global problem of a certain size, and split it up so that each of the processes solves part of the problem. Doubling the the number of processes means each process has a smaller sub-problem to solve, and as all the sub-problem are being done simultaneously the whole problem gets solved quicker. Thus you have a fixed problem size and vary the number of processes. You are varying both the global problem size and the number of processes.

Comment: Also stylistically Please use an mpi module rather than include the include file, it will catch many more errors in your code at compile time, and don't use the non-portable real(kind=8), use the much, much better style that you use in  the subroutine. Also be aware constants have a kind, and through not using that consistently you are probably losing precision. Finally it is much, much better to use module subprograms rather than external ones - again you will catch many more errors in your code at compiler time.

Comment: I also have a serial code and what I did was made the same m i.e m=3 for both serial and parallel. Run serial with 1 processor and parallel with 3 . Now I make say m=10 for both and run serial with 1  and parallel with 10 proc. and expected speedup. Isn't speed up=serial 1procesr/parallel n proc. ? is my code do loop which I want to be distributed in m processors is really distributed and each processor doing their respective job? don't know if each processors with respective ranks are doing that loop individually. To reach this point of MPI code this community helped me a lot. Thanks for that

Comment: And thank Ian Bush and Gilles as always for quick responses and comments

Comment: If `n` is a constant, then the amount of work per task remains constant when the number of MPI processes increase, so you should not expect any speedup.

Comment: Yes you are right Gilles. One quick question if you have time- Why my MPI_GATHER taking way much time? When I use t1=MPI_WTIME() just beginning of MPI_GATHER and t2=MPI_WTIME() just after MPI_GATHER above t2-t1 is consuming like 85% of the time of the whole code. Is MPI_GATHER that much time consuming?